# Workflow is taking so long to execute

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a workflow that runs every time an item is inserted/created in library. Workflow has two stages and it performs following operations

In Stage 1-

1. There are roughly around 120 IF statements that checks if a particular field is selected. If selected then the contents of a variable are concatenated with the old contents.
2. Sends email to user.
3. Create a new item in Issue Tracking list.

In Stage 2-

1. Assigns a user defined name to the file.

These are very simple steps and executing them it is taking roughly around 2 minutes.

I want this to be instant.

Comment: 2 minutes is far too much, but you could always run this script with a timer in shortened parts. With a sense of math this shouldn't be about the if statements. Some thoughts: Does the email arrive close to instantly (within 30 secs), or is this the part where it takes about 2 minutes? Very unlikely, but the mailing server could run ~1 minute behind the SharePoint's server time.

Comment: Its not about the email that is taking so long. I have used Log History list to see the execution. For executing suppose 10 IF statements it is taking 10 secs roughly or more. When it comes to statements where mail is to be sent it does not take much time.

Comment: is it also slow after you add a second item?

Comment: It is always slow. Even before I added any IF statement, then I was only generating the unique name of the file and once form is submitted that was also taking 5 seconds roughly to update the name. I had to refresh two or three times to see the name.

Comment: could you please check the guideline on this msdn article...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd441390(v=office.12).aspx this will help to improve the performance.

Comment: Are you running this locally or in O365?

Comment: I am running on O365